# Minor bug in C++ dfs question in a big test case

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I am solving a question on leetcode, my answer passed  123 test cases and failed on one. I can't figure out my problem because the test case is large and my solution works with every small testcase I could think of. The discussion section of leetcode wasn't helpful so I thought id try here.

question is: "You are given a map in form of a two-dimensional integer grid where 1 represents land and 0 represents water.

Grid cells are connected horizontally/vertically (not diagonally). The grid is completely surrounded by water, and there is exactly one island (i.e., one or more connected land cells).

The island doesn't have "lakes" (water inside that isn't connected to the water around the island). One cell is a square with side length 1. The grid is rectangular, width and height don't exceed 100. Determine the perimeter of the island."

```
example test case: [[0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0]]

Output: 16
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/island-perimeter/

my solution

```
    class Solution {
    public:

     bool dfs(unordered_set<string> & set, vector<vector<int>> &grid, int x,int y, int& count)
    {
        if(x>=grid.size()||y>=grid[0].size()||y<0||x<0) 
        {
            return false; // false means current coordinate is not an island piece
        }
        string loco=to_string(x)+to_string(y);
        if(grid[x][y]==0)
            return false;
        if(set.find(loco)!=set.end())
        {
            return true; 
        }

        set.insert(loco); //insert island piece to visited pieces
        int temp=4-(dfs(set,grid,x+1,y,count)+dfs(set,grid,x-1,y,count)+dfs(set,grid,x,y+1,count)+dfs(set,grid,x,y-1,count)); //subtract the number of adjecent island pieces
        count+=temp;
        return true;

    }
    int islandPerimeter(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        unordered_set<string>set;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0 ;i <grid.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<grid[0].size();j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j]==1) //find the first piece of island and run DFS
                {
                    dfs(set,grid,i,j,count);
                    return count;
                }

            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

I have checked the discussion section of leetcode but most of the solutions were iterative and didn't use DFS like i did. I am trying to understand what the problem is with my solution.

The testcase that failed is :

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0], 
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0], 
[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0], 
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], 
[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

expected output=128
my output= 125

Comment: From the [`[dfs]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dfs/info) tag wiki : *"DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]"*

Comment: *I am trying to understand what the problem is with my solution* -- Debug your code by using a debugger.  Step through the program a line at a time, and see where your program diverges from your expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `string loco=to_string(x)+to_string(y);` as the key for your `std::set`. Clearly, if `x = 11` and `y = 1` then the key is `111`, just as when `x = 1` and `y = 11`, which can break your algorithm.

Using a `std::string` as the set key is an unusual choice in the first place. I would recommend using `std::pair<int, int>` instead. Using your own type dedicated for this purpose (`struct Coordinate { int x, y; };`) would be even clearer but would need some additional boilerplate (namely `operator<`) to work with `std::set`, whereas `std::pair` has this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much that makes sense. But about the std::pair<int,int> part, I have a question. I don't think c++ unordered_set libary provides a hashfunction for this type of operator. (I tried it with vector and it didnt work). Since I am not working with set but I am working with unordered set its using a hash function to map my values. Do you have an alternative for this?

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar You're totally right, I never checked whether `set` actually was a `std::set` or a `std::unordered_set`. Yes, to use either `std::pair` or your own type with `std::unordered_set` you must provide a hash function, either as specialization of `std::hash<T>` or as `Hash` template argument of `std::unordered_map`. The comments here are not the place to elaborate further on that though. Maybe you could just use `std::set` though? `O(log N)` vs `O(1)` really won't make a meaningful difference for < 10k entries. Your solution has bad performance compared to the iterative one anyway ;)

Comment: (Adding a specialization of `std::hash<T>` for `std::pair<int, int>` is not allowed though, so don't do that.)

Comment: I added a comma to my string to distinguish the edge cases like this: string loco=to_string(x)+","+ to_string(y); and it worked. thanks again!